# d3v4 Lollipop chart - refactored conversion - static

Tags: javascript, d3.js

-- end goal
[image]

-- current attempt
[image]

I am interested in adapting the d3v3 lollipop chart into v4.

ref - https://bl.ocks.org/laysent/5739f087ec78e4386a6a

//version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/urmtj3v4/1/

//version 4 -- more simple variant - with placeholder circles as a POC
https://jsfiddle.net/ynmcfk3a/1/

^ but the circles are not sitting on the stalks correctly - they seem offset - what the issue is with the current calculation

```
                var lolliradian = 20;

                lollipop.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  //.transition()
                  //.duration(1000)
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.label) - x.bandwidth()/2 + lolliradian/2 ; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                    .attr("r", lolliradian)
                    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2");
```

Comment: a reference to something similar with animations - https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/lollipop_button_data_csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to finish conversion of the chart.

[image]

//d3v4 lollipop chart I
https://jsfiddle.net/ynmcfk3a/1/

A hybrid bar chart with circle tips.

LolliPop I

```
    <!--libs-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <!--js-->
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var $this = $('.lollipopchart');

            var data = [
                {
                    label: 'Toblerone',
                    value: 10,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Snickers',
                    value: 25,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Jawbreakers',
                    value: 60,
                },
                {
                    label: 'Gummi Worms',
                    value: 20,
                },
            ];

            var width = $this.data('width'),
                height = $this.data('height');

            var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                .range(["#eb6383", "#fa9191", "#ffe9c5", "#b4f2e1"]);

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.total = +d.value;
            });

            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 85, left: 20},
                width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var x = d3.scaleBand()
                      .range([0, width])
                      .padding(0.9);
            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .range([height, 0]);

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

            var svg = d3.select($this[0])
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr('class', 'lollipopchart')
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var lollipop = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'lollipop');

            var bars = lollipop
                .append("g")
                .attr('class', 'bars')

            bars.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                        return color(i);
                    })
                    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
                    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.total); });



                var lolliradian = 10;

            var circles = lollipop
                .append("g")
                .attr('class', 'circles');

                circles.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  //.transition()
                  //.duration(1000)
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return (x(d.label) + x.bandwidth()/2); })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                    .attr("r", lolliradian)
                .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                })


            var innercircles = lollipop
                .append("g")
                .attr('class', 'innercircles');

                innercircles.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  //.transition()
                  //.duration(1000)
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return (x(d.label) + x.bandwidth()/2); })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
                    .attr("r", lolliradian-5)
                .attr('fill', '#ffffff')



            lollipop.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                .selectAll("text")  
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

            lollipop.append("g")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        });

    </script>
    <!--js-->

    <!--css-->
    <style>
        body {
            background: #ffd;
        }
    </style>
    <!--css-->
</head>
<body>

    <h1>LolliPop I</h1>
    <!--html-->
    <div
        class="lollipopchart"
        data-width="300"
        data-height="300"
    />
    <!--html-->

</body>
```